# Re-partition Ubuntu Installation

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 from a CD-ROM. I selected the option to install Ubuntu along side Windows. I did not understand the slider for the partition for the install, so I just took the default. I discovered that half the of the available disk space was reserved for a Windows partition, and the remaining partition for Ubuntu. How do I extend/re-install Ubuntu to make use of that partition is reserved for Windows?

Comment: Open Gparted, make a screenshot of your current partitioning scheme and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

OK, you are basically asking two questions and I will provide answer for both.
Your problem is that apparently you accepted the default Ubuntu installation partition recommendation and now you want to give Ubuntu more space on your hard drive, correct?
Answers:

1. Without having to re-install Ubuntu, you can resize both partitions
   by booting into a Live CD (like the one you used to install Ubuntu),
   just make sure to select "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install" when the
   choice appears.  Then, go to the top left corner and hit the Ubuntu
   logo button, then type GParted.  When GParted opens up, you can
   re-size the Windows installation to make it smaller.  After this,
   make the Ubuntu installation bigger by filling in the empty space
   that the Windows installation left and wait for the process to end. 
   Exit the Live session and your partitions should be the size you
   want them. However, since Ubuntu has already been installed, this
   may (most likely) take longer than doing a fresh install which
   ultimately is what I recommend.
2. If you just barely installed Ubuntu and you don't have any work
   already saved in your installation, just go ahead and re-install. 
   It's the easiest and quickest way.  If you've already been working
   on Ubuntu for a while, try to save all that you can to an external
   hard drive or to a cloud service like Dropbox before doing the fresh
   install.  Just make sure that when you re-install you first delete
   the Ubuntu partition with GParted, then you make the Windows
   installation the size you want it to be and leave the empty space
   for the Ubuntu installation.  The installer should automatically
   choose the empty space to install Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try GParted and I tried to reinstall from my LiveCD. Both attempts failed. Maybe I don't understand enough about partitioning, but I deleted the partition ahead of the extended Ubuntu logical partitions. I could not increase the size of the extended partition. I thought the partition was still mounted. So, I tried to re-install. The issue is that the installation would have given me even a smaller partition for Ubuntu, and would not have used the space to the left of the partition. I'll live with the the space automatically assigned until next time.